# Create partition function based on join with other table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have 2 tables:

```
TableA
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
Date datetime
)

TabelB
(
Body XML,
KeyA uniqueidentifier
)
```

And I want to create partition for both tables based on date field in TableA.
I checked [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(SQL.90).aspx) but can't find any clue about it. Is it possible to do?

Comment: No. A partition function can only use columns of the table being partitioned. To do what you want, `Date` will have to become part of `TableB` as well.

Comment: that is so sad:-(